# ArrayList strange behaviour after update its values

Tags: android, arraylist, reference, duplicates, copy

I have a tabhost with several tabs and each tab contain a certain number of operations which are listed in a listview. To populate that listview I use an ArrayList.

First time tabs are created evertything works fine. The issue comes when I try to filter the list by year. The process of filtering works fine as I can see the filtered list in debug and it's fine.

The issue is that after filtering, i recreate the tabs in order to fill all listviews again. To open tabs I use this code. It creates as many tabs as different currencies there are in the list:

```
public static void openFragments(FragmentTabHost tabHost, ArrayList<Posicion> positions, Class FragmentResumen, Class FragmentDetails ) {

    //==========================================================================================
    //  This method open as many tabs as different currencies there are in positions list
    //==========================================================================================

    ArrayList<String> currencies = Currency.getDifferentCurrencies(positions);

    tabHost.clearAllTabs();

    for (int i = 0; i < currencies.size() + 1; i++) {

        String tabName = "", tabSpec = "";
        Class fragmentToOpen;
        Bundle arg1 = new Bundle();

        //A general tab is first created
        if (i == 0)
        {
            tabName = "All";
            tabSpec = "General";
            arg1.putString("moneda", tabName);
            arg1.putSerializable("posiciones", positions);
            fragmentToOpen = FragmentResumen;
        }
        //The rest of tabs for currencies are created
        else
        {
            tabName = currencies.get(i - 1);
            tabSpec = "Tab" + (i - 1);
            arg1.putString("moneda", tabName);
            arg1.putSerializable("posiciones", positions);
            fragmentToOpen = FragmentDetails;
        }

        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(tabSpec).setIndicator(tabName), fragmentToOpen, arg1);
    }
}
```

As I told before, this works fine always.

First time I need to create tabs I call it by using:

```
openFragments(tabHost, positions, FragmentResumenMedio.class, FragmentDetailsMedio.class);
```

Then I have a button that shows a DatePicker and when user selects a year I close the dialog and redraw tabs as follows:

```
ArrayList<Posicion> positionsFiltered = General.makeHardCopyOfArrayListPosition(positions);
            for(Posicion posicion : positionsFiltered)
            {
                Boolean matchFilters = filterPositionsByYear(posicion, year + "");
                if(matchFilters == false){
                    positions.remove(posicion);
                }
            }

            General.openFragments(tabHost, positions, FragmentResumenMedio.class, FragmentDetailsMedio.class);
```

When I debug this last function I can see that positions have the correct value after filtering but when I click the new tab, it shows the list without filtering and I don't know how could I solve this issue.

Thanks a lot.

EDIT

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //Initialize view and tabhost
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_medio, container, false);
    tabHost = (FragmentTabHost) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

    return tabHost;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


    //onCreatedView is only called the first time so we must ensure that tabhost is not null before adding tabs
    if(tabHost == null) {

        tabHost = (FragmentTabHost) getView().findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);
    }

    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.floatingButton);
    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            positions = new ArrayList<>(positionsFiltered);
            createDialogWithoutDateField().show();
        }
    });

    //Check if any update has been made since the last open
    SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    Boolean updateMedioRequired = prefs.getBoolean(updateOperationsMedioPlazo, true);
    if (updateMedioRequired != null)
    {
        if (updateMedioRequired == true)
        {
            //Update variable that indicates if changes have been made or not
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getActivity().getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putBoolean(updateOperationsMedioPlazo, false);
            editor.apply();

            //Check if there are previously stored operations
            if (operations.size() > 0)
            {
                //Show a progressDialog as prices have to be downloaded from internet and this can be a time consumming task
                progress = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Obteniendo precios",
                        "Un momento por favor...", true);

                //Generate positions from operations list and wait for result in "onStockPriceResult". If there are no changes, positions variable has already values
                if(positions.size() == 0) {
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            positions = MedioPlazoCalculations.generatePositions(listener, getActivity(), operations);
                        }
                    }).start();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Aún no se ha introducido ninguna operación", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //If no update needed, variable coming from MainActivity has positionList. Open as many new fragments as currencies there are in positionsList
            General.openFragments(tabHost, positions, FragmentResumenMedio.class, FragmentDetailsMedio.class);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    {
        if(getActivity()!=null)
        {
            Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
            positions = (ArrayList<Posicion>) bundle.getSerializable("posiciones");
            moneda = (String) bundle.getString("moneda");
        }
    }
}
```

Edit 3: If I place the commented instruction, filtering does not work. If I remove it, filtering works but I cant filter again because the value of the list has the filtered version not the original one

```
    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            positions = new ArrayList<>(positionsFiltered);
            createDialogWithoutDateField().show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: show your fragment code which is getting updated or filtered...just show that function.. for updation..or filtering of dates

Comment: The arrayList is the code being updated.

Comment: *show the fragmemt onCreateView() please..

Comment: please, see edit

Comment: I think the problem is with the arrayList positions, and positionsFiltered...but can't get it to work

Comment: I can see that in the following line (General.openFragments(tabHost, positions, FragmentResumenMedio.class, FragmentDetailsMedio.class);) the list is filtered but when the fragment is opened and I get data using bundle it has de unfiltered list.

Comment: override a function in your fragment.. `setUserVisibilityHint() { if(getActivity()!=null) { // get the new filtered bundle data here }}` add this.. and your code will work.. let me know if it works..

Comment: That code is not being executed

Comment: whats the issue ??

Comment: just override the method and use your logic there..if the fragment stays at back stack that method is executed..

Comment: See edit2: Positions is null later in the program.

Comment: so you are having trouble passing the positions ??

Comment: No, if I place the bundle inside onCreate it gets executed. In the method you suggested inever gets executed

Comment: the filtered position ??

Comment: Only first time. Second time not refreshing

Comment: See Edit 3, please

Comment: ok you can do one thing make your position variable static..and instead of passing the value through bundle.. do `fragment.position = filteredList;` and init the views again in the method i have told you..

Comment: not all views but the view that changes accroding to the filtered list

Comment: issue was onCreateView was not being called always. I changed my code to onViewCreated and now works fine.

Comment: yes thats why i asked you to use setUserVisibility hint ...everytime i updated any view i had done in that method.. :)

Comment: but as you are not getting value from bundle there..